# How to access a variable from one class into another class on different files in same package in java

Tags: java, class, variables, scope

I have file Sender.java and another Receiver.java. In my main class which is in file Main.java, I created an object for both. I want to access a variable that is in my Sender class into Receiver class. what is the simplest way to do it. I extended the Sender class onto my receiver class and it serves the purpose. Albeit, is there any other way to do it?

**Main.java**

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Sender sender=new Sender();
        Receiver receiver=new Receiver();
        sender.show();
        receiver.show();


    }
}
```

**Sender.java**

```
class Sender{

    static int val=0;
    public void show(){

        System.out.println("Sender value="+val);
        val++;  
    }

}
```

**Receiver.java**

```
class Receiver{
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Receiver value="+val);  
    }
}
```

Comment: create getter and setter of your variable then in the main method `Sender sender = new Sender(); sender.getYourVariable();`

Comment: and please show us your code, so we can understand more

Comment: i modified the question with the codes I use

Comment: so you want to use val of Sender in Receiver class?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, getters and setters should be your answer. [Why use getters and setters/accessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors) explains the purpose of them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to make the variable public. although this is not necessary if the classes are in the same package.
The more important issue here is - you need to pass an instance of `Sender` to `Recevier`.
You also need to understand whether you want the variable static or not.  My guess - not static (so a different copy of the variable with every instance of `Sender`)

```
class Sender{

    public int val=0;
    public void show(){

        System.out.println("Sender value="+val);
        val++;  
    }

}

class Receiver{
    public void show(Sender s){
        System.out.println("Receiver value="+s.val);  
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Sender sender=new Sender();
        Receiver receiver=new Receiver();
        sender.show(sender);
        receiver.show();


    }
}
```